# How do I concat grouped rows as a single row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a query like `SELECT CONCAT(manufacturer, ':', COUNT(*)) AS count FROM cars GROUP BY manufacturer` which returns something like:

```
+---------+
| count   |
+---------+
| ford:10 |
| fiat:5  |
| kia:2   |
+---------+
```

Now I want to GROUP_CONCAT those rows into 1 row like:

```
+------------------------+
| result                 |
+------------------------+
| ford:10, fiat:5, kia:2 |
+------------------------+
```

But there's already a GROUP BY, so GROUP_CONCAT doesn't work.  How can I achieve this with MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Group_Concat(count SEPERATOR ',') from 
(SELECT CONCAT(manufacturer, ':', COUNT(*)) AS count
 FROM cars GROUP BY manufacturer) AS A
```